# Effect size calculation for comparison between medians

Tags: statistical-significance, effect-size, median

I have two groups of samples - disease and normal. I have calculated whether there exists any statistically significant difference between the medians of the two groups via the Mood's median test. The p-value results indicated that I have a significant difference with an $\alpha$ of 0.1. Now I want to calculate the effect size between the two groups. I was planning on using Cohen's d, which is given by $d=m_1-m_2/s_p$, where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the means of the two groups and $s_p$ is the pooled standard deviations for the two groups. My question is whether I can modify this formula to calculate the effect size for the medians between two groups,where $m_1$,$m_2$ will be medians instead of means. Is it the right way to do that?

Comment: 1. Don't expect there to be "*the*" right way. There might be something that makes a kind of sense, but there might be many other things. 2. Effect size would be a population quantity. You can't calculate it, if you're doing a sample size calculation you specify it. You might attempt to *estimate* it from a sample, though; is that what you mean?  3. Nevertheless, thinking first in population terms, did you have some measure of spread in mind for the denominator? (Presuming standard deviation doesn't make sense for whatever you're using this for) . . .

Comment: . . . 4. on a related note -- what led you to look at difference in medians?

Comment: I have a bunch of boxplots and I want to compare the medians and see for a significant increase/decrease. For the significance test, I have used the Mood's median test but for the effect size I am unsure what to use.

Comment: If you already have boxplots, are you looking at *post hoc* estimates of effect size?

Comment: @Glen_b not sure about OP's use case, but I compare medians fairly often as I have distributions skewed in one direction. Also, given that they are using Mood's test, which is a chi-square test, there are pretty decent (well, standardy, anyway) methods for measuring effect size.

Answer (score 3):

Cohen's *d* is probably not the best effect size statistic for a comparison of medians, since it is based on the mean and standard deviation(s), and is related to the calculations used in a *t* test.

I haven't seen this anywhere that I remember, but I suppose you could use an analogous statistic that uses the differences in medians and the median absolute deviation.

```
(median(B) - median(A)) / sqrt((mad(A)^2 + mad(B)^2)/2)
```

For normal samples, this will give a similar result to Cohen's *d*.

If I invented this, you can call it Mangiafico's *d*. :)

Of course, a simple difference in medians is also a useful effect size statistic.  It isn't unit-less, but has units of the measurements.  If you add confidence intervals, this is quite informative.

Finally, effect size statistics that might be used for a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test would be useful:  Vargha and Delaney’s *A*, Cliff’s *delta*, and the Glass rank biserial coefficient.

***Addendum November 2022:***

I added an implementation of the statistic that uses the differences in medians and the median absolute deviation to my *rcompanion* package.  An example follows.

```
Group1 = c(0,  4,  8, 12, 16, 1,  5,  9, 13, 17,  2,  6, 10, 14, 18)
Group2 = c(8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26)

library(rcompanion)

mangiaficoD(x=Group1, y=Group2, verbose=TRUE, ci=TRUE, hist=TRUE)

   ###   Group  Statistic Value
   ### 1     A     Median  9.00
   ### 2     B     Median 17.00
   ### 3       Difference -8.00
   ### 4     A        MAD  7.41
   ### 5     B        MAD  7.41
   ### 6       Pooled MAD  7.41
   
   ###       d lower.ci upper.ci
   ### 1 -1.08    -2.81   -0.169

Group = factor(c(rep("I", length(Group1)), rep("II", length(Group2))))
Value = c(Group1, Group2)
Data = data.frame(Group, Value)

plot(Value ~ Group, data=Data)

library(coin)

median_test(Value ~ Group, data = Data)

    ### Asymptotic Two-Sample Brown-Mood Median Test

    ### Z = -2.1589, p-value = 0.03086
```

***Addendum 2***

I mentioned Vargha and Delaney’s *A* above as an option for effect size.  This statistic is based on the proportion of observations in Group A that are greater than observations in Group B, and so on.

For the example above, the proportion of observations in *Group1* > *Group2* is 0.16, and  the proportion of observations in *Group2* > *Group1* is 0.80.

These statistics are useful to report when comparing two medians.

```
library(rcompanion)

vda(x=Group1, y=Group2, verbose=TRUE)

   ###            Statistic Value
   ### 1 Proportion Ya > Yb  0.16
   ### 2 Proportion Ya < Yb  0.80
   ### 3    Proportion ties  0.04
   
   ###  VDA 
   ### 0.18
```

Comment: I like the Mangiafico's d, not sure how you gonna call the median version of Glass' delta then? :) Btw, I think VDA (or any other stochastic superiority-based effect sizes) is not linear in scale, how useful you think they are if someone wants to add them up, for example, to prove synergetic effect compared with addictive effect. Thanks

Comment: @panda , Well, I doubt you can add VDA values in some meaningful way.  Unless you have the original data and can re-calculate the statistic for the given scenario.  For readers, the comments here might be useful in this context:  [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574309/comparing-multiple-algorithms-pair-wise-with-vargha-delaney-a-measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574309/comparing-multiple-algorithms-pair-wise-with-vargha-delaney-a-measure)

Answer (score 1):

Mood's test is really just a chi-square test in disguise (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_test).

Hence, I recommend using the measure of effect size for chi-square tests. There are three standards used: phi, the odds ratio, and Cramer's V. The first two are only defined when comparing two samples, while Cramer's V works for nxn contingency tables.

Here are equations for phi and V:

$$\phi= \sqrt(\chi^2/n)$$
$$V=\sqrt(\chi^2/(n \min(c-1, r-1))$$

where n is the total number of observations, $\chi^2$ is the test statistic, and r/c are the dimensions of the contingency matrix (in this case it will be two x the number of groups you are comparing). If you are interested in the odds ratio, I would recommend googling it, as it is a little bit more complicated than the others.

Note I leave interpretation of the effect size to the reader. :)

https://www.real-statistics.com/chi-square-and-f-distributions/effect-size-chi-square/